# Java Logic Error While Loop with JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I am running into a logical error with my web service. Instead of returning the total price, it returns 0. This is because it asks for another return statement at the bottom of my code, is there anyway around this error? Thanks in advance for the help

```
public int checkPart(java.lang.String partname, int quantity) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ConnectionString);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT PartName, Price, Quantity FROM parts WHERE PartName =" + partname + ";");
        while (rs.next()) {
            int PriceVar = rs.getInt(1);
            int total = PriceVar * rs.getInt(2);
            return total;
        }
        rs.close();
        return 0;
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe the query failed because you forgot to put quotes around the partName parameter in the query? Question is a little vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format.

```
int total = 0;
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ConnectionString");
    // ...
    if (rs.next()) {
        int PriceVar = rs.getInt(1);
        total = PriceVar * rs.getInt(2);
    }
    rs.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    if (con != null) {
        con.close();
    }
}
return total;
```

Comment: It's still returning 0 for some reason.

Comment: Your query should probably be "SELECT Price, Quantity FROM parts WHERE PartName = '" + partname + "'"

Answer (score 0):

you had better add the break in the while to get first result:

```
int total = 0;
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ConnectionString");
    // ...
    if (rs.next()) {
        int PriceVar = rs.getInt(1);
        total = PriceVar * rs.getInt(2);
        break; // get first one
    }
    rs.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WarehouseWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    if (con != null) {
        con.close();
    }
}
return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` function of **SQL** instead of doing this

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM table_name;
```

This will **return sum** of the price column from you table **table_name**

**Edit:**

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM parts WHERE PartName =" + partname + ";");
```

**P.S** Take the concept, don't just copy paste the query. It may have issue of not includeing apostrophes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, your query isn't correct (and you really should bind parameters). Short answer, change this

```
WHERE PartName =" + partname + ";");
```

to

```
WHERE PartName ='" + partname + "';"); // <-- single quotes.
```

But, I think you really wanted something like (using [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to clean-up)

```
public int checkPart(String name, int quantity)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://ConnectionString";
    String sql = "SELECT Price FROM parts WHERE PartName=?";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getInt(1);
        }
    }
    throw new SQLException(String.format("No PartName={%s} Found", name));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When this type of situation declare one local variable and return it at last. Try to avoid more then one return it will make confusion.
You can use sum method of sql by that you can easily get sum of all and you can avoid loop.